# Vue Eventbus: handler.apply is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, event-bus

I want to reload one of my components when an other component changes (for example I send a put with axios)

I tried it with eventbus but I got this error:

> handler.apply is not a function

In the component where I want to trigger:

```
EventBus.$emit('compose-reload', Math.random()*100);
```

Where I want to be triggered:

```
<template>
    <div class="">

        <div class="">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column is-one-fifth">
                    <div class="box">
                        <Menu></Menu>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-four-fifth">
                    <div class="box">
                        <router-view :key="key"></router-view>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Menu from './includes/Menu'

    import EventBus from '../../../event-bus';

    export default {

        components: {
            Menu,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                key: null
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            EventBus.$on('compose-reload', this.key);
        },
        created(){
            this.key = Math.random()*100
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EventBus.$on` expects a handler function as a second argument but the variable `this.key` is passed in, hence the error.

You should change this :

```
mounted(){
   EventBus.$on('compose-reload', this.key);
}
```

To this :

```
mounted(){
   EventBus.$on('compose-reload', key => {
     this.key = key;
   });
}
```